# PC not booting after enabling secureboot in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios, secure-boot

I tried to Multiboot my Laptop with secureboot enabled,  I installed fedora on one SSD and had Windows 11 on the other one. Then I generated a new key for the UEFI. I enabled secureboot in the UEFI and could use Linux.

Then I tried booting in to the UEFI and it only had a black screen. I tried to shut it off and on but now it only shows a black screen. The fans are working and I can enable the RGB on the keyboard.

I already tried to reinstall the BIOS, connect it to a second monitor and insert a bootable USB stick. I also pressed every key combination imaginable. The only thing that shows an image is if I press win+ v, than it shows a message: "CMOS checksum invalid". I have a button that says reset but it doesn't change anything. Does anyone has some ideas?

My Laptop:
HP Omen 17-cb1087ng

- i7 10750h
- rtx 2080 Super
- 32gb RAM

Comment: Remove the CMOS battery.

Comment: I read it's build in to the battery and I already removed it. But thanks though

Comment: How did you reinstall the BIOS if you can't get video & the only time you do is when it shows an error?
Have you tried a power discharge? Remove power cord & battery (even if internal) then hold power button for 10sec or so, it's fixed some random things from my experience

Comment: You may need to [follow these instructions 3-'Recover the BIOS'](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/omen-17-cb1000-laptop-pc-series/32827283/model/35718973/document/ish_3932413-2337994-16): from PC off hold Win+B then press button 2-3sec then let go of power button while continuing to hold the other keys hopefully a screen comes up after some beeps. There is more guidance at the link

Comment: I followed them already but it doesn't do anything, except booting, shutting down booting again and shutting down. The only thing that changes is the light on USB drive, it stays is on.